# rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec failures. chapter 5 in Michael Hartl's guide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

i can't figure out what is causing the failures! this is my first post on stackoverflow so i apologize in advance if i left out some needed info.. okay here is the failure...

```
Failures:

1) Static pages Help page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Help" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

2) Static pages About page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About Us" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

3) Static pages Contact page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
   expected css "title" with text "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact" to return something
 # ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.35756 seconds
9 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:19 # Static pages Help page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:26 # Static pages About page 
rspec ./spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb:33 # Static pages Contact page
```

here is my routes.rb

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
root to: 'static_pages#home'

match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

static_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Static pages" do

subject { page }

describe "Home page" do
before { visit root_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sample App') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('')) }
it { should_not have_selector 'title', text: '| Home' }
end

describe "Help page" do
before { visit help_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Help') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Help')) }
end

describe "About page" do
before { visit about_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'About') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('About Us')) }
end

describe "Contact page" do
before { visit contact_path }

it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Contact') }
it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Contact')) }
end
end
```

contact.html.erb

```
 <h1>Contact</h1>
 <p>
 Contact Ruby on Rails Tutorial about the sample app at the
 <a href="http://railstutorial.org/contact">contact page</a>.
 </p>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= render 'layouts/shim' %>    
</head>
<body>
<%= render 'layouts/header' %>
<div class="container">
  <%= yield %>
  <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have any `content_for :title` in contact.html.erb, so your title tag shouldn't contain shat you expect

Comment: i'm not following you sorry. can you please try and explain again?

Comment: your `yield(:title)` won't do anything unless you add a `content_for :title` in `contact.html.erb`

Comment: I posted an answer that goes into a little more detail about it, and you can also watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tests are failing because your application layout is yielding the title, but you aren't setting the title anywhere. When you see `yield :something` in a view, such as for the title, it means the view will render whatever content it knows about for ":something". In your case, the title is being yieled via the following:

```
<title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
```

In order to tell Rails what content you want "title" to yield, you need to set it in your view with:

```
content_for(:title) { 'My Title'}
```

It can be tedious to have to repeat this in every view, so many people will create a helper for title:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def title(page_title = '')
    content_for(:title) { page_title }
  end
end
```

Then in your view you can just do:

```
<%= title 'My Title' %>
```

Check out [Railscast #30](http://railscasts.com/episodes/30-pretty-page-title) for more information on this technique